# What is the deal with this usb drive with a second block device?

Tags: partition, usb-drive, fdisk, lsblk

I have a giveaway usb stick and when I plug it into my computer and run `lsblk` it shows *two* block devices, i.e. `sdb` and `sdc`. `sdb` of them contains almost all the free space ( ~15G) and the `sdc` one is very small (32M) and contains stuff like images of the company who gave the usb stick away. 
I would like to get rid of the `sdc` one (more out of curiosity). However, these are apparently not partitions on the same hard drive (otherwise lsblk would show something like `sdb1` and `sdb2`, right?).

Last but not least I can't even run `fdisk /dev/sdc` as it's apparently a `Read-only file system`.

Can I get rid of this `sdc` device or at least wipe it clean. And what are the inner workings of this? Is `sdc` a second physical drive?

Comment: lsusb should give you more info on what the system sees, but yes, they are two separate disks.  A quick google search turns up a lot of other drives that are created this way as well.

Comment: Do you know the manufacturer of the USB stick?

Comment: @bgregs `lsusb` gives the same output whether or not the usb stick is plugged in. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Bodo Unfortunately I don't know the manufacturer.

Comment: Maybe you can use the USB IDs to find out the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are USB sticks that present itself as two drives: a CD-ROM (readonly) and  a mass-storage device (read/write). 
This was invented to allow auto-starting an application when the USB stick is plugged in on a windows system.

There may exist a removal tool from the manufacturer. 
Example: Sandisk U3. Search for keywords: sandisk remove u3 launchpad

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. After a bit of searching i compiled the u3-tool from the [source](https://github.com/marcusrugger/u3-tool.git) but it still says `Read-only file system`. Other users seem to have the [same problem](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=235498). It might work on windows, though..

Comment: I once had two U3 USB sticks from Sandisk. IIRC on one of them I removed the CD-ROM partition with Sandisk's Windows program. I don't know the open source tool. You might be able to check from the contents of the partitions if it really is U3 or something else. Unfortunately I have lost my U3 stick, so I cannot tell you what you should look for.